# Repository getting data from Yaml file

Tags: symfony, yaml

I have a bunch of entities which are not user-created nor dynamics (they are part of the application data).

So instead of storing them in DB, I would like to keep them in Yaml files to keep them versionned.

I wonder if there is a good practice to load them : custom repository maybe ? I would like, if possible, to do as with Doctrine : `$this->getEntityManager()->getRepository()-findAll()` for example.

Is it possible or do I need to re-code everything myself ? Thanks a lot and have a good day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use YAML based repositories frequently.  Here is an example:

```
namespace Cerad\Bundle\LevelBundle\InMemory;
class LevelRepository implements LevelRepositoryInterface
{
protected $levels = array();

public function __construct($files)
{
    foreach($files as $file)
    {
        $configs = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents($file));

        foreach($configs as $id => $config)
        {
            $config['id'] = $id;
            $level = new Level($config);
            $this->levels[$id] = $level;
        }
    }
}
public function find($id)
{
    return isset($this->levels[$id]) ? $this->levels[$id] : null;
}
public function findAll()
{
    return $this->levels;        
}
```

Notice that it implements find and findAll thus emulating a Doctrine repository.  In fact, it was designed to be interchangeable with a Doctrine repository in case I decided to use Doctrine.  This example only shows two repository methods but additional ones can be added as needed.

I define this to be a service:

```
# services.yml
services:

cerad_level__level_repository__in_memory:
    class:  Cerad\Bundle\LevelBundle\InMemory\LevelRepository
    arguments:  
        - '%cerad_level_level_files%'

cerad_level__level_repository:
    alias: cerad_level__level_repository__in_memory
```

The cerad_level_level_files parameter is defined in a config file so I can adjust which files to load the levels from.

Access the service from a controller with:

```
$levelRepository = $this->get('cerad_level__level_repository');
```

I define all of my repositories (including Doctrine repositories) as services and use a simple get instead of $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository()...

The alias lets me switch between yaml repositories and doctrine repositories without changing my application code.  Just for completeness, here is how you define a doctrine repository as a service:

```
cerad_game__game_repository__doctrine:
    class:  Cerad\Bundle\GameBundle\Doctrine\EntityRepository\GameRepository
    factory_service: 'doctrine.orm.games_entity_manager'
    factory_method:  'getRepository'
    arguments:  
        - 'Cerad\Bundle\GameBundle\Doctrine\Entity\Game'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understood your question correctly but in Symfony you have a YAML component to parse YAML files to an array.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/introduction.html

I think you can work with that component.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not worried about the parsing, but about loading the instances. I would like to do it in a "DB-style", like with Doctrine, because I will have relations between YAML-loaded entities and DB-loaded entities.